# Getting angle from atan2

Tags: math, vector, cocos2d-iphone, angle

I have simple Question about atan2() that how to get the angle from the the Turret so that it follows spaceship where it goes.

i have a vector which is from the Turret to SpaceShip but as of my knowledge atan2f gives the angle from the hypotenuse to 0 Degree line.

please correct me if i am wrong.

[image]

I want that angle highlighted as (blue) so that it follows where the spaceship goes.

Here is my Code:

```
-(void) upDateTurret:(CCTime)delta{

CGPoint playerToCannonVector = ccpSub(_playerSprite.position, _turretSprite.position);

float angle = atan2f(playerToCannonVector.y, playerToCannonVector.x);

_turretSprite.rotation = 90.0f - CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
}
```

this give me the correct result but how? as atan2f gives the angle which is from hypotenuse to 0 degree line(red angle).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
// Calculates the angle from one point to another, in radians.
//
+ (float) angleFromPoint:(CGPoint)from toPoint:(CGPoint)to {
    CGPoint pnormal = ccpSub(to, from);
    float radians = atan2f(pnormal.x, pnormal.y);

    return radians;
}
```

It basically matches your own code; the only real difference is that you are subtracting the result from 90.0 degrees which is what I think you're missing.  Remember that a rotation of 0 degrees would normally be pointing "north" to the top of the screen (at least that's how it works for me).

To convert an angle from a north=0 to east=0, I use:

```
// Converts an angle in the world where 0 is north in a clockwise direction to a world
// where 0 is east in an anticlockwise direction.
//
+ (float) angleFromDegrees:(float)deg {
    return fmodf((450.0f - deg), 360.0);
}
```

Comment: i am subtracting 90 degree from the result because in cocos2d rotation starts from North and in maths rotation starts from east direction.

Comment: I've added another method I use to manage that difference between Cocos2D and "maths".  Again, I don't recall needing to make that translation.